# Is there any source code example of using IUPnPRegistrar.RegisterDevice?

Tags: delphi, upnp

I am testing on Windows uPNP.  The IUPnPRegistrar has RegisterDevice and UnregisterDevice methods.  How may I use RegisterDevice to register device to uPNP service in Windows?  I can't find any example in google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [UPnP dimmer device sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Dimmer-Device-2274e56d)
2. [UPnP device registration sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Register-Device-d0cbfba2)